# jsp page move to next page on validation fails

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have put a duplicate check on my form. I used below to get the boolean value if the submission fails.

```
String result = request.getParameter("status");
```

but the issue is resulting gets the value to 0 when I click on submit and page forward to next page. I want to stay on the same page if result zero.
 Please help me.
Thanks,

Comment: javascript != java

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if..else statement to control the redirection of the page.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    //.... your code here ....
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
    if (result != 0) {
         requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/thankYou.jsp");
         requestDispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    } else {
         requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/samePage.jsp");
         requestDispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new in Java, Can you please help me where this code will come. My this code is in three form. 1 id .jsp 2nd is action.java and 3rd is struts-config.xml. please help where i put this check?

Comment: The variable "result" that you have defined, takes the value of "status" that the user introduces in your id.jsp. When the user clicks on submit, the class action.java is called. And in this class is where you have to define your function doGet() or doPost() to implement the reditection to another page like your id.jsp or another controller like action.java